# req.cookies returns undefined but cookies are set

Tags: javascript, express, cookies

I am using `cookie-parser` in my express app. When the root page is requested I set a random number on the cookie using `res.cookie(name, value)` and it sets it fine (I checked on my browser console). But when I try to log `req.cookie` it always returns undefined.

Here's my code:

**routes.js**

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

var movieTrailer = require('movie-trailer');

var Promise = require('bluebird');
var logs = require('log-switch');
var fs = require('fs');
//var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

//Setup x-ray for scraping
var Xray = require('x-ray');
var x = Xray();

var debug = false;

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Page requested!');
  console.log('Cookies: ', req.headers.cookies); // For some reason this returns undefined

  var scrapeMovies = function(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
      fs.readFile('moviesRT.json', (err,data) =>{
        var movies = JSON.parse(data);
        resolve(movies);
      });
    });
  };

scrapeMovies().then(
    movies => {
      var randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * movies.length);
      res.cookie('randomInt', randomInt);
      var randomMovie = movies[randomInt];
      movieTrailer(randomMovie.title, (err, url) =>{
        console.log('Requesting trailer: ', randomMovie.title);
        if(err) throw err;
        var embedUrl = url.replace('watch?v=','embed/');
        console.log('Video ID: ', url.slice(32,url.length));
        randomMovie.trailerURL = embedUrl; //Add the embed URL to the randomMovie object before rendering it
        res.render('main',randomMovie,
        (err, html) =>
        {
          if(err) throw err;
          console.log('Rendering...');
          res.send(html);
          console.log("Done!");
        });
      });
    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');

//Define app and settings
const app = express();
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const port = 3000;

var routes = require('./routes');

var debug = true;

app.use('/', routes);
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(cookieParser());
//app.use(cookieParser());

//View engine
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log(`Server Starts on ${port}`);
  if(!debug) logs.disable(); //Disable logging if debug variable is false
});
```

Comment: The correct header is `req.headers.cookie`

Answer (score 12):

You either want to check `req.headers.cookie` which will be set by express.

Or if you want to use the the parsed result of the `cookie-parse` middleware that is stored in`req.cookies` then your problem is the order in which you register your routes and the middleware.

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(cookieParser());
```

The parsing of the cookie is done after the routes in `routes` have ben executed.

You need to move the `cookieParser()`  before the route where you want to use it.

```
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use('/', routes);
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you. Changed `cookieParser()` before routes and it works! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

This solved my problem:

Basically when you are sending a request to the server from client-side, make sure you add `withCredentials: true`. For example

```
{
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }),
    'withCredentials':true
  };
```

Comment: Worth to note that without "withCredentials": true no cookies will be send

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me, when I sent a `PUT` request from the client-side (Angular) without passing the `body` object.

I was doing this (second argument missing):

```
requestBranchEditPermission() {
  return this.http.put<IPutProfile>(`${this.api}/some-endpoint`, this.options).toPromise();
}
```

instead of this:

```
requestBranchEditPermission() {
  return this.http.put<IPutProfile>(`${this.api}/some-endpoint`, {}, this.options).toPromise();
}
```

Comment: you are my savior! thanks! I was having this issue with a `post` request (angular client)

Comment: "without passing the body object.", this is unrelated and misleading. The third argument for put is the header. You passed header information as body of request.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to read the cookies as `req.cookies['cookie-name']` and set the cookies as `resInit.cookie('cookie-name', 'cookie-value')`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

in the frontend add `credentials : 'include'` as an option to your fetch API

A more elaborated code below for a get request

```
fetch('url', {credentials: 'include'})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => //do something with the data)
.catch(err => console.log(err.message));
```