# JWT - req.cookies is undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cookies, jwt

[STATEMENT -
I have posted 2 hours ago about this topic, but actually, my request was not consistent enough to make you understand my struggle. I could edit, but many of you wouldn't have seen the update. Then I have added much content here. I apologize if it's not a good practice to re-post.
]

I would like to know what is wrong with my current code about retrieving the value present in req.cookies.

After success of a user log in, I'm sending an access token within a cookie into the user's browser (as you can see below)

[image: screenshot from devtools]

Once, the user is logged in, he is redirected to another page, it is at this point that middleware in my Node/TS API check if he has the right or no. here is the code of the MW

```
import {Request, Response, NextFunction} from 'express'
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

export default function authToken(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const authCookies = req.cookies['auth-token']
    console.log('authCookies', authCookies)

    const token = authCookies && authCookies.split(' ')[1]

    if (token == null) return res.sendStatus(401) // unvalid
    
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err: any, user: any) => {
        
        if (err)return res.sendStatus(403) // no longer valid

        res.locals = {
            ...res.locals,
            token: user
        };
        next()
    })
}
```

I only get an undefined output from `const authCookies = req.cookies['auth-token']` and I can't understand why

Also, an extract of req

```
  body: {},
  secret: undefined,
  cookies: [Object: null prototype] {},
  signedCookies: [Object: null prototype] {},
  route: Route {
    path: '/main/wallet',
    stack: [ [Layer], [Layer] ],
    methods: { get: true }
  },
```

here is how I declare my token

```
            const accessToken = jwt.sign({id: existingUser.id}, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, { expiresIn: '15s' })
            res.cookie('auth-token', accessToken, { httpOnly: true });
```

My Index.ts setup

```
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:8080'}))
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
```

How I handle it in React

```
     axios({
        method: 'post',
        url,
        data: store.getState().user.signInData,
        withCredentials: true,
      })
        .then((res) => {
          dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data));
          dispatch(getMainWallet(res.data.id));
        })
```

Comment: Where are you using the `authToken` function middleware?

Comment: hey @SebastianAmmon, I'm using it in my router as following 
router.route('/main/wallet').get(verifyToken, controller.getMainWallet.bind(controller))

Comment: did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46567030/5165465