# req.cookies returning empty on node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cookies

I am trying to implement a cookies/jwt based authentication system for my react js app, but upon checking for the auth cookie server side, req.cookies returns empty even though the cookie appears in the browser. Does anyone know why that is or how I can access the cookie directly from the browser?

```
//called by passport.authenticate successful redirect
app.get('/createAuthCookie', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('req body', req.user)
  if(req.user){
    const token = jwt.sign(req.user, process.env.AUTH_SECRET, {expiresIn: '8h'})
    res.cookie("token", token, {
      maxAge: 1000*60*60*8, 
      httpOnly: false, 
      secure: false, 
      //sameSite: false
    })
    console.log('heres your cookie', req.cookies) //returns with the correct cookies, works great
    res.redirect('https://localhost:3000/postmanager')
  }
  else res.status(500)

})

//called by react component fetch method
app.get('/getAuthCookie', (req, res) => {
  console.log('stored cookies', req.cookies) //never works, always returns [Object: null prototype] {}
  var cookie = req.cookies.token
  console.log('sent cookie', cookie)
  res.json(cookie)
})
```

Could the issue be that /getAuthCookie is called by a front end component so req is pointing elsewhere?

Comment: Are you using cookieParser? Otherwise only `req.headers.cookie` will be defined. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46567030/4384238

Comment: @DemiPixel yes, cookieParser is used at the top of the file